# MS Access VBA format Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, formatting, vba

Hi I am trying to format an excel spread sheet created by my MS access macro. I wanted to select rows with only values in it. So for example I want to select the first row and text wrap it

I thought this logic would work, but gives me error 1004 (Application-defined or Object defined Error)

```
Dim my_xl_app As Object
Dim my_xl_workbook As Object

Set my_xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set my_xl_workbook = my_xl_app.Workbooks.Open(C:\PATH)

For x = 1 To 23
my_xl_workbook.sheets(x).Range("A1",my_xl_workbook.sheets(x).Range("A1").End(xlToright)).WrapText = True
Next x
```

`my_xl_workbook.Sheets(x).Range("A1", my_xl_workbook.Sheets(x).Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).WrapTex‌​t = True` is what is being highlighted when I press debug

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `For` loop is looping through Worksheets `my_xl_workbook.sheets(x)` so unless you have 23 worksheets it will through an error 1004 because the worksheet you're trying to select doesn't exist.  I think from your question you're attempting to loop through the rows on a worksheet.

Comment: @gordon Hi Thank your for the answer, I have 23 worksheets that I am looping through, and I want to format each of the top rows I originally had
`my_xl_workbook.sheets(x).RANGE("A1:AB1").WrapText = True`
which worked but then I realized that not all my sheets were same length so when I ran my next formatting code `my_xl_workbook.sheets(x).RANGE("A1:AB1").Autofilter`
it filtered more than I needed on some spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not closing properly the file, thus it stays opened and unvisible. Check in your task manager how many excel files do you have opened. Try to close them all. Furthermore, you refer to `xlToRight`, which is member of the `MS Excel Object Library`, which is not present in your application.

Thus, try the following:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim x               As Long
    Dim my_xl_app       As Object
    Dim my_xl_workbook  As Object

    Set my_xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set my_xl_workbook = my_xl_app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\v.doynov\Desktop\file.xlsx")

    my_xl_app.Visible = True

    For x = 1 To my_xl_workbook.Sheets.Count
        With my_xl_workbook.Sheets(x)
            .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).WrapText = True

            Debug.Print "Wrapping " & .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(-4161)).Address & _
            " From " & .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(-4161)).Parent.Name

        End With
    Next x

    my_xl_workbook.Save
    my_xl_workbook.Close (True)

End Sub
```

This is how I found `-4161`. Add a reference to `MS Excel 14.0 Object Library` in the Visual Basic Editor.

[image]

Then in the immediate window write `?xlToRight`. Thats quite enough.

Comment: Thank you for the response, So I just went into task manager, and indeed there was a lot of excel processes running , so I closed those. But I still get the same error the only thing I changed from your code was the path.

Edit:
If It helps `my_xl_workbook.Sheets(x).Range("A1", my_xl_workbook.Sheets(x).Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).WrapText = True` is what is being highlighted when I press debug

Comment: Thats strange. Try again with the new code with `debug.print` and see what is it printing in the immediate window.

Comment: So I copied your new code, and it's stopping at `.Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).WrapText = True` with nothing in the Immediate window

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the correct path? And that you have all possible Excels closed?

Comment: Yes, everything is closed and it is the correct path, I renamed my file to 123.xlsx and chose an easier path to test and still same results. "C:\Users\Desktop\123.xlsx"

Comment: And if you comment the code giving you the error, does it work ok? Do you get plenty of stuff in the immediate window?

Comment: I get the same error right in the next line `Debug.Print "Wrapping " & .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Address & _
            " From " & .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Parent.Name`

Comment: I see. The point is that you are using late binding from Access and it does not recognize the `xlToRight`. Thus, you should be using `-4161` instead. Try again the code :)

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! But why is it -4161? what is late binding?